# Automatic delete of an OneToMany entity in java spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm using spring jpa. I have a main entity with an one to many list connection to another entity.

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PendingRoundInfo> pendingRoundInfos;
```

I would like that when I remove an entity (PendingRoundInfo) from the list and then save the main entity that the removed item will be deleted from the DB automatically without calling repository.delete();

The current result is that the entity is removed from the one to many connection table but still exist on its own.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the object, make sure that `List<PendingRoundInfo>` is still attached to the session, and call `entityManager.merge(Parent Object)` then `entityManager.flush()` or `commit()` based on your transaction configuration.